# relative to ng-include in Aurelia.js

Tags: javascript, aurelia, aurelia-templating

I want import to my main html few other parts like heder, footer, so can I do this in aurelia?

I tried this bellow and did not work

```
<template>
 <import from='header.html'></import>
 <import from='footer.html'></import>
</template>
```

Comment: http://aurelia.io/hub.html#/doc/article/aurelia/templating/latest/templating-dynamic-ui-composition/3

Answer (score 3):

The syntax is:

```
<template>
  <require from='./header'></require> <!-- this "requires" the component -->
  <require from='./footer'></require>

  <header></header> <!-- this "uses" the component -->
  <!-- content -->
  <footer></footer>
</template>
```

If your component is composed of a view and view-model pair, you just have to use `<require from="./header"></require>`. If it is composed of only a view, then you have to put '.html' at the end, like this `<require from="./header.html"></require>`